# Selenium Webdriver Python - how to click the right number in randomly changed JS buttons?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, button, random, click

when the page is refreshed, the place of the numbers changes randomly between 2 tables.
So the thing I want to do, for example:
I should write "01234" as a password, but the problem here, the place of these numbers change randomly when the page refreshes.

What can we click the right numbers?
I put the screenshots below.

Thanks for your help.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath to get elements by text:

```
password = "01234"
for n in password:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//td[@class="chiffre" and .="{n}"]').click()
```